# Bigcommerce Stencil SKU number on Category pages

Tags: bigcommerce

I currently see {{product.sku}} which is tied to product page.

I need to show sku number on category/search pages but there is not global property.

Editing templates > components > products > card.html

If you know of any solution or point me in the right direction, that would be a help.

thanks you in advance :)

Comment: If your store is live, post the URL to a category page and I will show you how to load the SKUs with Ajax.

Comment: this is the clients live url: http://festoolshop.ca/power-tools/drills/

Comment: @suhdo where you able to find a solution?

Comment: I'm about to post an answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, tailored to your site specifically, on how you can load the SKU from each product page, and then insert it on the category page. This code should go on the category page. It is meant just as an example, you may have to modify it to work on your site.

```js
// For Each Product...
$('.product').each(function(i) {
  // Get the product URL 
  var url = $('> article > figure > a', this).attr('href'); // http://screencast.com/t/qBgwszhhpFiz

  // Perform GET
  getProductSKU(url).then(function(sku) {
    console.log(sku);
    // do something with the sku
    // such as append it to the product, maybe above the 'add to cart button'
  });

});

/**
 * Performs HTTP Get to a given product page
 * and returns the SKU on that page. 
 * @param url <string> - The product URL to GET
 * @return Promise - Resolved with product SKU on success. 
 */
function getProductSKU(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type:'GET',
      success: function(data){
        resolve($(data).find('#sku-value').text()); //Return the SKU - http://screencast.com/t/zlCAftmekgp
      },
      error: reject
    });
  });
}
```

Links:
http://screencast.com/t/qBgwszhhpFiz 
http://screencast.com/t/zlCAftmekgp

Comment: Thanks!! Got stuck trying and trying to find a way through stencil utils but there's none. Stupidly I was running out of ideas on a way to have the product color swatch persisted from the category page to the product page. You can now change color on the products grid and go to the product page landing on that same color. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do an ajax load() call to pull in this information to the page you need it on, but there's not currently a helper or data exposed by the product card to support this.

Comment: I tried below but no luck...

$('mydiv').load('{{url}} #sku-value');

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution to show SKU in the product card on category page.
you can add a code in the product card inside the card body.

```
<div class="pro-row wrap-stock-card">
    <dt class="productView-info-name">{{lang 'products.sku'}}</dt>
    <dd class="productView-info-value">{{sku}}</dd>
</div>
```